# Is there anyone you can use .NET Core Packages in a non .NET application (SignalR Package)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

So got a problem with  SignalR and want to upgrade the SignalR package to use the .NET Core one but the problem is the application is using 4.6.2 Framework. Is there anyone this can be done?

- Can't move the application and upgrade to .NET Core at the minute

Comment: You *can't* use .NET Core packages in .NET Framework. There's a SignalR package for .NET Framework though. You don't have to use the .NET Core package

Comment: `So got a problem with SignalR` what problem? Even if that's solved by upgrading, Visual Studio/NuGet will show you the latest .NET *Framework* version, not the .NET Core version. Did you try to add the .NET Core version manually?

Comment: Very unclear what you want/need to do, but SignalR has complete support for .Net Core but you might need to use a newer version as well as convert the whole app/server/??? to .Net Core? [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I would argue that you should try to fix it. Also try upgrading to 4.8.

Comment: The latest SignalR version for .NET Framework is [2.4.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR), released in January 2022. There's no newer version to upgrade to. ASP.NET Core SignalR is a complete rewrite so you can't combine them anyway